# SQL Case statement based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update, case

I need to create a query that includes a CASE statement that basically says

```
CASE if getdate() > datedue by 31 days
    then status = 'Blocked
END
```

Does anybody know how to check if todays date is greater than say, 25/10/2012 by 31 days?

EDIT

```
Select co.OrderID, cu.FName + '  ' + cu.SName as 'Name', 
cu.Address1 + ', ' + cu.Address2 + ', ' + cu.Address3 as 'Dispatch Address', 
cu.PostCode, 
ma.MaterialName as 'Item',
mi.Price as 'Item Price',
co.DateOrdered as 'Order Date',
pm.DueDate,
pm.Overdue,

HERE I NEED TO WRITE A CASE STATEMENT TO INSERT INTO A LOCKEDACCOUNT TABLE
so for example CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), pm.DueDate) >= 31 THEN INSERT INTO LOCKEDACCOUNT (id, status, datelocked, customerid) VALUES (.....)
END

from Customers cu
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), @duedate) >= 1 THEN 'blocked' 
    ELSE 'Not' 
  END AS Status;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6426)

**Note that:** If you didn't specify an `ELSE` clause, the default will be `NULL`.

**Update:** You can insert into a table with `CASE` expression like so:

```
INSERT INTO Statuses VALUES
(CASE 
   WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), CAST('20121025' AS DATE)) >= 31 THEN 'Blocked' 
   ELSE 'Not' 
 END);
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc7ac/1)

Comment: could an insert be created to depending on if the duedate is > 31 days? so for example when ABS(DATEDIFF(dd,  getdate(), datedue)) >= 31 THEN INSERT.......

Comment: @Annoscia - Do you want to Update or insert?

Comment: the update works now thank you, but i think i may receive more marks on my assignment if i use an insert based on the CASE being > 31 days

Comment: @Annoscia - Can you edit your question and show me the table structure and explain what are you trying to do in details, may be I can help you.

Comment: @Annoscia, So you need to insert into the  table `LOCKEDACCOUNT` the values from that you select from customers table? If so, the table `LOCKEDACCOUNT` contains `id, status, datelocked, customerid`, but these are not what you are selecting from the `select` clause?

Comment: im adding the values in myself so INSERT INTO LOCKEDACCOUNT (id, status, datelocked, customerid) VALUES ('blocked', getdate(), 2), i just need to know if the way im thinkin of doing it would work?

Comment: @Annoscia - So you are adding the values for `id, datelocked, customerid` by yourself. But what about the value for the `status` field? You are selecting it with the case expression like in my answer, but based on the `pm.duedate` right? If so, do you select only one value to insert only one value and which value do you select? Or do you inserting mutliple values from customers into the table  `LOCKEDACCOUNT `? Because the two cases had different syntaxes.

Comment: yes i need to insert the values by myself but only if the duedate is > than 31 days.  so instead of using the update, i need to say, select the columns as above, then check to see if duedate is > than 31 days, if it is then insert the values in to the lockedAccount table, if not then do nothing.

Comment: @Annoscia OK, Fine. But the customers table contains a lot of values in `duedate` column, which value of these values do you want to compare it in the case expression. Do you want to compare the latest duedate or what?

Comment: hi mahmoud i think i have miss understood a few things, im sticking with the update case statement but many thanks for all of your help

Comment: @Annoscia, OK, but if something goes wrong don't hesitate to ask any time. Or you can post a new question explaining the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CASE 
   WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,@duedate,getdate()) >= 31 then 'Blocked' else 'NO' end
```